# Webpack - turning off requests to /sockjs-node/info or specifying a different port

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

I run Django and Vue together and the combination works fairly well.  Django runs on http 8000 and webpack dev server chugs along on port 3000, JS or Vue changes get compiled automatically and I just have to reload the page (this is not an SPA app).

[Django-webpack loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) is used to serve the bundles via tags like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/static_src/bundles/pssystem/data.js" ></script>
```

I do not use Vue-CLI and have no intention to move from a Django to a Node frontend.

Life is good, everything else works fine.

The only annoying bit is repeat requests like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/sockjs-node/info?t=1607750560606
```

This is what the devtools show for host:port requests.  App is on 8000 w. Django, bundles 3000 with devServer, socksjs needs to be on 3000 too.

[image]

Now, Django doesn't find that resource so its log clutters up with 404.  I actually coded a 410 instead, but, no, Vue is just going to ping and ping and ping that 410.

```
#urls.py
url("^sockjs-node/info", views.nodeinfo),

#views.py
def nodeinfo(request):
    return HttpResponseGone()
```

Now, I have tried to look for this.  The answers on the Vue forum are multiple and most involve changing to **vue.config.js**, located next to **package.json**.

UPDATE:  since I am NOT using Vue-cli, it seems the settings need to go in **webpack.config.js** instead.

After trying 2 or 3 of the suggestions, most of which don't seem to make much sense (a localhost question ends up with a "fix" consisting of a devserver entry pointing to `0.0.0.0` for example), none of them work.

`devServer` configs which have NOT helped:

```
{
    hot: false,
    port: 3000
};

{public: 'localhost:3000'}

{sockPort: 3000}

{sockPort: 3000,sockHost: 'localhost'}

{inline: false}
```

None of the threads I have seen seem to hold very authoritative answers.  Or, more likely, I can't find the correct answer in all the noise that is being posted.

(I did see one suggesting to change the webpack command instead by adding `--no-inline` flag, but haven't tried it out).

I won't be running node in production, will only run webpack bundling to staticfiles.  I don't care about https here.  I also don't care to get sockjs working by reconfiguring stuff - things work perfectly well without whatever is missing, so turning it off can't hurt.

I ONLY want those requests to STOP going out from the client code.  Entirely.  How do I do that?

(P.S. If you want to answer, please indicate in what way your proposed contents of **vue.config.js** address the issue - I have just seen too many *this fixed it* with not the slightest bit of info on how the configuration contents serve to turn this off.  That means whoever uses that solution doesn't understand it and uses copy-and-pray programming).

Versions:

```
vue@2.6.11
webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
npm --version 6.14.6
node --version v10.15.0
```

#### Last but not least, these are my webpack goals:

- **Watch** and recompilation on the server whenever I change the JS/Vue files, bundles on 3000 are refreshed.
- The main server functionality stays with Django serving up html via server-side templates, on  a different port than node's devServer.
- No need for **hot module reload** on client.  It is perfectly OK for me to keep using the stale bundles until I refresh the page.  **This is not, and could not be, an SPA or Node frontend app**.

Comment: a grep of running or listening shows *ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000*.  The scripts entry in **package.json** for running the dev server is simply `"scripts": {"watch": "node server.js"},`.

Comment: So, yes, Vue isn't going to find anything about node on port 8000, that's Django and Django is not configured to reroute that request to node on port 3000.  I understand that, but it also seems not having this request succeed doesn't really hurt anything.  So I would rather turn those requests off entirely than wire up Django to sockjs.

Answer (score 4):

(OP's edit:  this answer got the bounty, because it told me Vue was less relevant here than Webpack and because my investigation of Webpack's relevant configuration option then showed nothing that manage to turn off these requests.  The takeaway I have for now is that this can't be done - *as far I understand*, if Django is serving at :8000 then Webpack HMR's implicitly expects to be able to poll at the same host:port, without an option to re-route or turn it off.  So, the tentative answer is more of a *no, can't be done*).

Since you're not using the Vue CLI, you'd need a *webpack.config.js*, rather than *vue.config.js*.  Assuming your `devServer` is running at `localhost:3000`, (I'm not certain about your non-standard setup) you can try this in *webpack.config.js* in your project root:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

If this doesn't work, I recommend recreating your project with Vue CLI and using a separate repo/*package.json* for your backend in a *server* folder.

Comment: Txs for your help.  That made no difference.  The devServer is already doing fine at localhost:3000 and the bundles are working fine in practice.  I just want the browser to stop sending out socketjs requests, on any port or server.  It doesn't **need** them to operate, or else nothing would work.

Comment: Must do it somewhere else because it looks at 8000 for socketjs.  The bundles are served up at 3000 via [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader), that's just in the JS script tags.  So I don't think Vue is really *aware* of node's location at all, it really doesn't have to be.  So I am guessing it *assumes* it can ask at the site's overall address, at localhost:8000, i.e. basically `/` as far it is concerned. That's the thing - a pure Vue + Node config using Vue-CLI is only of limited guidance to integration with Django.  Txs again.

Comment: *webpack.config.js* isn't Vue though.  As far as I understand it, the request for Sock is the Webpack bundle trying to send a request back to the `devServer` (it's for Hot Module Reload, by the way).  django-webpack-loader may shed some light on why it's looking at 8000.  Maybe it has to be configured inside that loader's options

Comment: But yeah, save yourself a lot of trouble:  Recreate your frontend project in Vue CLI.  Create a server directory and create your backend project there.  Nice and simple, two repos, two *package.json*, much less hassle.  You'd also get the benefits of Vue CLI + community solutions

Comment: I am thinking what's going on is all the devServer configuration stuff only affects the *server* side of things.  I.e. where does Node *serve* its bundles.  That is undoubtedly port 3000.  But it doesn't affect where *client* code is expecting to find sockjs, which is *assumed* to be on the same localhost/port as `/` on port 8000.  So, in any non-Node app, which is definitely what a Django front end is, client code will NOT use the devServer's port.  Maybe it's a different setting?  Dunno, but this sockjs is a very minor issue and I expressly can't/don't want to use a full Vue frontend.

Comment: No, that isn't the case (at least with Vue CLI, probably in raw Webpack too).  For example, when I serve a default Vue CLI app, the output shows the app is running-- i.e. `devServer` is running-- on the following location: (which is the `devServer` default)  "Local: `http://localhost:8080/`" and "Network: `http://X.X.X.X`", where the network is my network IP address.  I get the same error because the bundle attempts to communicate with Sock on my network IP, but is denied.  When I configure `devServer` to `host: 'localhost'`, the bundle requests there instead and the error is fixed.

Comment: Maybe, but that's the hostname part of things.  There is no mechanism *for the client* to specify a different *port* for the html (8000 Django) and sockjs (3000).  I tried playing with `{public: 'localhost:3000'}`.  No effect.  This whole set of configuration only works for a node-run frontend.  I'll probably bounty it up later on, because it is of general interest to the non-Node frontend stack.

Comment: Well, that was only an example, `port` is specified in the same way.  Bounty sounds good though.

Comment: Your answer didn't really give me what I wanted, but it is the only answer, did put me on the track of looking more closely at webpack's settings and leads me to believe that Vue does not really have much involvement with this and that webpack may not provide the turn-off capability I was looking for.  So, since I did not get any other answer and am out 150 bounty anyway, I'd like to award it to you, as long as we can agree on some verbiage up top that it is more indicative that there may be no solution to do this with devServer than a solution in its own right.   What do you think?

Comment: Hey, one more thing.  Try `sockHost` and `sockPort` with my answer first.  (I don't mind changing the answer, but I would guess there is a way and someone out there knows it.  But I'll gratefully accept the points if they'll disappear otherwise.)

Comment: I'll try sockport and sockhost again.  But I believe they're more intended for where the server should be serving rather than where the client should be polling.  I tried it and still saw the same localhost:8000 requests going out.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer: Additional requests to `http://localhost:8000/sockjs-node/info?t=123` with the wrong port may be caused by a **webpack plugin**. In my case the culprit was ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin. The solution was to tell that plugin which port webpack dev server was on:

```js
// …in webpack.config.js…

plugins: [
  isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
    overlay: {
      sockPort: 3000, // <-- Tell plugin which port WDS is running at
    },
  }),
].filter(Boolean),

devServer: {
  hot: true,
  port: 3000, // I used port 3000 here because of the setup in OP's question
}
```

Docs: https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin